# Some people who hate noise should not live in the city. In the attributive clause, who refers to ‘some people’ or ‘people’？

Tags: word-usage, attributives

> Some people who hate noise should not live in the city.

In the attributive clause, **who refers** to **some people** or **people**？ Or both have the opportunity?

Answer (score 1):

In an integrated (defining) relative clause, the relative pronoun usually refers to the nominal (noun phrase minus determinative).

> The most central and most frequent type of relative construction is the integrated relative. It usually functions as a modifier **within a nominal constituent**.
>
> Huddleston & Pullum (2002: 1034)

Therefore, in your sentence, "who" refers to "people", and not "some people".

Comment: Perfect answer!